# Python 3: do strings have __next__() method?

Tags: python-3.x

```
>>> s = 'spam'
>>> s.__next__()
```

Result is:
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    s._*next*_()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_*next*_'**

But in the documentation http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types we  can read about iterator types:

**Python supports a concept of iteration over containers. This is implemented using two distinct methods; these are used to allow user-defined classes to support iteration. *Sequences, described below in more detail, always support the iteration methods.***

Below described are: sequence Types — str, bytes, bytearray, list, tuple, range.

So, why str does not support **next**()?

Answer (score 4):

Strings don't have the `__next__` method, but `str_iterator` objects do.
You have to call `iter` on your string to receive an iterable (`str_iterator`) object.

```
>>> s = 'spam'
>>> g = iter(s)
>>> g
<str_iterator object at 0xad91d0>
>>> next(g)
's'
>>> next(g)
'p'
>>> next(g)
'a'
>>> next(g)
'm'
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

It's important to understand that an iterator has to be a separate object, because otherwise you wouldn't be able to have multiple iterators for the same object at the same time:

```
>>> g, h = iter(s), iter(s)
>>> next(h)
's'
>>> list(zip(g, h))
[('s', 'p'), ('p', 'a'), ('a', 'm')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterator types and container types are not the same thing.

To get an iterator object, you need to call `__iter__`, as stated in the docs you link to:

```
'spam'.__iter__().__next__()
```

or better

```
next(iter('spam'))
```

Comment: why doesn't this last one iterate when you say a = next(iter('spam))   and then call a multiple times. It just produces 's' every time

Comment: @chimpsarehungry Because a new iterator is created every time. Assign it to a variable: `i = iter('spam')` and then call `next(i)` multiple times to get the desired result.

Comment: Is there any way to go back through the iteration. Like last(i) ?

Comment: @chimpsarehungry No, there is not. If you need random access, use a container (such as a `list`).

Comment: @chimpsarehungry last element probably want `string[-1]` to explicitly access last element, if you want to iterate in reverse you can use [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed)